# \t characters in twig output

Tags: php, templates, twig

anyone knows how to make [twig](http://www.twig-project.org) stop outputting \t and \n characters?
my output looks like this:

```
<ul>\n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<li>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=''> ...
```

for this template:

```
    <ul>
        {% for datum in this.data %}
        <li><a href='#'>link</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

thanks!

Comment: `\t` and `\n` are tabs and newlines; do you mean that Twig prints `\t`, or does it print tab characters ?

Comment: whats this.data contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right, as it says in the [Twig manual for whitespaces](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control):

> Whitespace is not further modified by the template engine, so each
>   whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) is returned unchanged.

You can use the **`spaceless`**-tag to suppress whitespaces.

```
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}

{# output will be <div><strong>foo</strong></div> #}
```

Have a look at the manual for further options.

Comment: great! thank you very much. I've missed that part of the docs :S. I was actually looking for a way of doing it globally... but it seems that there isn't.

Comment: If you put your highest level template in between those tags then it will affect all included and derived templates as well.